# Not receiving Delivery notifications in CDO

Tags: asp.net, email

I have a function that uses CDO to send emails with request to have a delivery receipt when the mail reacehes the recepient.

I use the following code:

```
CDO.Message msg = new CDO.Message();
CDO.Configuration conf = new CDO.Configuration();

conf.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"].Value = 1;
conf.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"].Value = txtHost.Text;
conf.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"].Value = 25;
conf.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"].Value = txtPass.Text;
conf.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"].Value = txtUser.Text;

conf.Fields.Update();

msg.Configuration = conf;

msg.To       = txtTo.Text;
msg.From     = txtFrom.Text;
msg.Subject  = txtSubject.Text+" " + DateTime.Now;
msg.HTMLBody = txtBody.Text;
msg.BodyPart.Charset = "utf-8";

msg.DSNOptions = CdoDSNOptions.cdoDSNSuccessFailOrDelay;
msg.Fields.Update();
msg.Send();
```

Now this works fine on my local machine with my web server, but when used in the production server with another mail server the delivery receipts were not received.

I believe there must be a difference between my mail server and the production mail server but I don't know what it can be exactly.

So please if anybody has faced such a problem before, tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on your local machine almost by accident because you're delivering it to yourself. To work out in the world [you have to explicitly tell CDO not to deliver to the local smtp](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302839) for relaying by specifying [sendUsingPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527265(v=EXCHG.10).aspx)

> conf.Fields["ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"].Value = 2